# How can I reset openedx static files cache?

Tags: python, django, memcached, openedx

I need to know how to force the openedx lms/cms to clear static files cache. When I browse the lms for example, I got the static files like that

```
/static/css/lms-style-vendor.XXXXXXX.css
```

I need to get the original source of this file not the cached one with XXXXXXX token. Or even generate a new one.

Also when I run django server, it take a while to load the modification in HTML templates.

Comment: Did you find the answer? as I am facing a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49296522/openedx-native-installation-theme-change-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and figure out a way. You need to re-compile the theme. Here are the steps.

```
sudo -u edxapp bash
source /edx/app/edxapp/edxapp_env
cd /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform
paver update_assets cms --settings=aws
paver update_assets lms --settings=aws
exit
```

This will update the files that are served from `/edx/var/edxapp/staticfiles/images`