# Openedx Native installation : theme change not working

Tags: django, openedx

I have installed openedx using `Native installation` method. Now I want to change the default logo. As a test, i removed the logo from the folder `/edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform/lms/static/images`. 
But when i open the `localhost`, its still there. `(lms view)`.

In inspect view, the logo name appears as `/static/images/logo.b6c374d66d57.png`.

The same operation when I perform in `devstack`, The logo changes successfully.

What am I missing?

Since I am using the default theme, I think I don't need to configure anything regarding theme customization.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am posting the answer as I figure it out. Maybe helpful for someone.
The application was service data from `cache` and I had to recompile the theme again. Following are the steps to compile the theme.

```
sudo -u edxapp bash
source /edx/app/edxapp/edxapp_env
cd /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform
paver update_assets lms --settings=aws
```

If there are changes in cms contents, execute

```
paver update_assets cms --settings=aws
```